# Python random.seed behaved strangely

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I called random.seed(234), then called random.randint(0, 99) and received 92.  When I repeated this process again several times I received 86.  When I called random.randint a second time then it return 92.  I was expecting the first value to be 86 not 92.  Why was it 92?

The full log output is below.  I've included all of it incase there was some previous action that can explain the seemingly buggy behaviour:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: import string

In [3]: string.letters
Out[3]: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

In [4]: string.ascii_letters
Out[4]: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

In [5]: string.printable
Out[5]: '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'

In [6]: len(string.printable)
Out[6]: 100

In [7]: [string.printable[random.randint(0,99)] for i in range(20)]
Out[7]: 
['{',
'+',
'[',
'\r',
'R',
'Z',
'v',
'|',
'v',
'e',
'T',
'x',
'\\',
'}',
'0',
'>',
'V',
'\n',
'`',
'`']

In [8]: ''.join([string.printable[random.randint(0,99)] for i in range(20)])
Out[8]: '%Z\\%mx4Z53uUZIa5KHe*'

In [9]: ''.join([string.printable[random.randint(0,99)] for i in range(20)])
Out[9]: 'Fg\nDHW+oV?-9``}\x0by%xD'

In [10]: import os

In [11]: os.urandom(1)
Out[11]: '('

In [12]: os.urandom(1)
Out[12]: '8'

In [13]: os.urandom(1)
Out[13]: '\xb1'

In [14]: os.urandom(1)
Out[14]: ')'

In [15]: os.urandom(1)
Out[15]: '\x8c'

In [16]: os.urandom(1)
Out[16]: '^'

In [17]: os.urandom(1)
Out[17]: '{'

In [18]: os.urandom(1)
Out[18]: '\x8f'

In [19]: ''.join(os.urandom(10))
Out[19]: '{t\x8dR\x1d\x83\xef\xd6N\xbd'

In [20]: ''.join(os.urandom(10))
Out[20]: '\x96\\\xf6\xe3\xf4/\x1f\xc7\x90\x02'

In [21]: from random import SystemRandom

In [22]: crypt = SystemRandom()

In [23]: ''.join([string.printable[crypt.randrange(100)] for i in range(20)])
Out[23]: "WoDVH\r1!?1+djB'f<;nW"

In [24]: ''.join([string.printable[crypt.randrange(100)] for i in range(20)])
Out[24]: '\rf?zo`7^{Y_Zx^[SYw7c'

In [25]: ''.join([string.printable[crypt.randrange(100)] for i in range(20)])
Out[25]: "3k*uGVIP'~^{P*~bserk"

In [26]: ''.join([string.printable[crypt.randrange(100)] for i in range(20)])
Out[26]: '~lkM/a&#_F&D\n<sC&i\r\n'

In [27]: random.seed(234)

In [28]: random.randint(0,99)
Out[28]: 92

In [29]: random.seed(234)

In [30]: random.randint(0,99)
Out[30]: 86

In [31]: random.seed(234)

In [32]: random.randint(0,99)
Out[32]: 86

In [33]: random.seed(234)

In [34]: random.randint(0,99)
Out[34]: 86

In [35]: random.randint(0,99)
Out[35]: 92

In [36]: random.randint(0,99)
Out[36]: 48

In [37]: random.seed(234)

In [38]: random.randint(0,99)
Out[38]: 86

In [39]: import sys

In [40]: sys.version_info
Out[40]: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=13, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

In [41]: sys.version
Out[41]: '2.7.13 (default, Dec 17 2016, 23:03:43) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]'
```

** **edit, weird: "same" seemingly buggy behaviour repeated** **
In the same terminal window I closed the previous ipython session.  I did some command line activity, then I opened ipython again.  I did some different work.  Then I tried this again:

```
In [37]: import random

In [38]: random.seed(234)

In [39]: random.randint(0, 99)
Out[39]: 85

In [40]: random.randint(0, 99)
Out[40]: 50

In [41]: random.seed(234)

In [42]: random.randint(0, 99)
Out[42]: 86

In [43]: random.randint(0, 99)
Out[43]: 92
```

Comment: python 3.4 `>>> random.seed(234)
>>> random.randint(0, 99)
43
>>> random.seed(234)
>>> random.randint(0, 99)
43
>>> random.seed(234)
>>> random.randint(0, 99)
43`. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: tested with python 2.7, different value but same each time as well...

Comment: Yeah, weird huh.  Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I guess this is an edge case bug or a documented but surprising behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's happening here is that something in the IPython system is making use of the `random` module, and so consuming numbers from the random stream provided by the core Mersenne Twister generator. That means that if you're also using the `random` module, you only see an unpredictable subset of the numbers from the stream, since IPython gets the rest.

I can reproduce the effect you're seeing reliably (on both Python 2 and Python 3) by hitting the `<Enter>` key a few times randomly between invocations of `random.randint` (though actually I'm using `random.random` for simplicity). Here's one example session, with Python 3.6.2 and IPython 6.2.0 on macOS 10.12.6.

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: random.seed(234)

In [3]: 

In [3]: 

In [3]: random.random()
Out[3]: 0.8579160018299248

In [4]: random.random()
Out[4]: 0.5055065431394443

In [5]: random.seed(234)

In [6]: random.random()
Out[6]: 0.26476014305349627

In [7]: random.random()
Out[7]: 0.8579160018299248

In [8]: random.random()
Out[8]: 0.5055065431394443
```

To check my hypothesis, I hacked in an override to the `Random.random` method in the `random.py` file in the standard library, by adding the following method to the `Random` class:

```
def random(self):
    print("random being called")
    import traceback; traceback.print_stack()
    return super(Random, self).random()
```

Now launch IPython, and hey presto! Lots of tracebacks. I won't reproduce the tracebacks in full (they're long), but here's the tail end of one of them:

```
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 376, in prompt_for_code
    pre_run=self.pre_prompt, reset_current_buffer=True)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/interface.py", line 415, in run
    self.eventloop.run(self.input, self.create_eventloop_callbacks())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/eventloop/posix.py", line 157, in run
    random.shuffle(tasks)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 278, in shuffle
    j = randbelow(i+1)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 250, in _randbelow
    r = random()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 98, in random
    import traceback; traceback.print_stack()
```

As you can see, the [`prompt_toolkit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/prompt_toolkit) library, which is used by IPython, uses the random module to shuffle its tasks (though this change was recently removed, according to the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/4476b3c28add85c5a8169fbb81ded8c3b845e588/CHANGELOG#L8)).

If you need a reliably reproducible random stream, create an explicit `random.Random` instance and use that:

```
In [1]: from random import Random

In [2]: my_random = Random()

In [3]: my_random.seed(234)

In [4]: my_random.randint(0, 99)
Out[4]: 43

In [5]: my_random.randint(0, 99)
Out[5]: 33

In [6]: my_random.seed(234)

In [7]: my_random.randint(0, 99)
Out[7]: 43

In [8]: my_random.randint(0, 99)
Out[8]: 33
```

Comment: Interesting and scary at the same time! And nice analysis.

Comment: What if you want to generate something from another distribution? Say, normal?

Comment: @NewNameStat: I think all of the same reasoning applies, since `random.gauss` (for example) is taking its random input from the same stream as `random.randint`. So the rule again is that if you want reproducible random results, instantiate and use your own `Random` instance `my_random` and use `my_random.gauss` in place of `random.gauss`.

Answer (score -1):

My Python 2.7.5 can not reproduce the same behavior, but the documentation 
 ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html ) says

> If a is not None or an int or a long, then hash(a) is used instead.
>   Note that the hash values for some types are nondeterministic when
>   PYTHONHASHSEED is enabled.

I would (just opinion) say that it can be caused by the nondeterministic behavior of the hash function. Is your PYTHONHASHSEED enabled?

Comment: How do you tell?  I did `'PYTHONHASHSEED' in os.environ` and got `False`.

Comment: This shouldn't apply here: `PYTHONHASHSEED` doesn't affect the way that integers hash.